# Avoid side effect when initializing object in class attribute

Tags: python

With the following code:

```
from functools import partial

def get_data(query):
    result = query.search()
    print(result)
    return result

class Query:
    def __init__(self):
        print('side effect')

    def search(self):
        print('searching')
        return '123'

class News:
    sourcing_handler = staticmethod(partial(get_data, query=Query()))

    def source(self):
        self.sourcing_handler()

news = News()
```

what would be the best way to avoid printing `side effect` when `News` is initialized?

In theory I could turn `sourcing_handler` to a full-blown method to get rid of this:

```
@staticmethod
def sourcing_handler():
    return partial(get_data, query=Query())
```

But it is less... declarative? Are there any better ways to achieve this (descriptors?)?

Comment: In the actual code, *why* does `Query` constructon have a side effect; and why must that side effect be avoided, but only some of the time? "In theory I could turn sourcing_handler to a full-blown method to get rid of this:" The two versions of the code aren't equivalent; `staticmethod(partial(get_data, query=Query()))` calls `staticmethod` directly on the partial, while the decorator version calls `staticmethod` on a *function that returns* a partial.

Comment: And could that side effect be elsewhere, perhaps in a `@classmethod` like `create_with_side_effect(cls):` that does the side effect and then returns a new instance?

Comment: Default parameter `True` if to print? `def __init__(self, print_message=True) if print_message: print('side effect')`

Comment: @KarlKnechtel: Valid points, thanks. Regarding "why must that side effect be avoided, but only some of the time" - I don't really want to avoid the side effect; I just don't want Query to be initialized (and causing the side effect) when the file is read by Python.

Comment: Well, when **do** you want it to be initialized? And *should* it use the same `Query` instance whenever the method is called without an explicit argument?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel: Ideally I would like the query to be initialized ony when `sourcing_handler` is actually called. I am not sure I get your second point but I think Query instance can be the same all the time.

Comment: You can, for example, use `None` as the default and special-case it.

Comment: Is there a particular reason for `source` to exist, and call `sourcing_handler`? Why not just rename `sourcing_handler` to `source`? (Asking this not to criticize, but to try and figure out what to suggest. I assume your real code is doing more stuff.)

Comment: @CrazyChucky: You're definitely onto something, at the moment `source`  does not do more than just call `sourcing handler`.  The reason why  both `source` and `sourcing_handler` exist is because I meant `News` to be subclassed, and each subclass would only have to provide different value for `sourcing_handler` attribute, and inherit  the default implementation of `source` from base `News` class (which again, does not do much at the moment,  but I thought it might change in the future; maybe I am worried prematurely).